# Count iteration number with Fortran omp parallel do for indexing?

Tags: fortran, openmp

I want to fill a matrix in parallel and I'm having troubles figuring out how to keep track of the iteration number with OpenMP.

This is my current subroutine:

```
subroutine predictions(N, N_samples, idx_new_a, idx_new_b, idx_new_c, K, &
                         pred_idx_a, pred_idx_b, pred_idx_c, X, meanX, sdX, &
                         a, b, c, beta, mu_a, sigma_a ,  sigma_b, sigma_c, &
                         y_pred_draws, nthreads) bind(C, name="predictions_")
  integer, intent(in)                                     :: N, N_samples, &
                                                             idx_new_a, &
                                                             idx_new_b, &
                                                             idx_new_c, &
                                                             K, nthreads
  integer, dimension(N), intent(in)                       :: pred_idx_a, &
                                                             pred_idx_b, &
                                                             pred_idx_c
  double precision, dimension(N,K), intent(in)            :: X
  double precision, dimension(K), intent(in)              :: meanX, sdX
  double precision, dimension(N_samples,idx_new_a-1), intent(in)      :: a
  double precision, dimension(N_samples,idx_new_b-1), intent(in)      :: b
  double precision, dimension(N_samples,idx_new_c-1), intent(in)      :: c
  double precision, dimension(N_samples,K), intent(in)    :: beta
  double precision, dimension(N_samples), intent(in)      :: mu_a, sigma_a , &
                                                             sigma_b, sigma_c
  integer, dimension(N_samples*N,4), intent(out)          :: y_pred_draws
  integer                                                 :: n_rows, idx, &
                                                             sample, iter
    iter = 0

    !$ call omp_set_num_threads(nthreads)
    !$omp parallel do
    do idx=1,N
       do sample=1,N_samples
              iter = iter + 1                 ! I KNOW THIS IS WRONG BUT I'M NOT SURE HOW TO FIX IT
          !WRITE(*,*)  'Iteration ', iter
          y_pred_draws(iter, 1) = idx
          y_pred_draws(iter, 2) = sample
          CALL pred_iter_idx(N, N_samples, idx_new_a, idx_new_b, idx_new_c, K, &
                             idx, sample,pred_idx_a, pred_idx_b, pred_idx_c, &
                             X, meanX, sdX,a, b, c, beta, mu_a, sigma_a ,  &
                             sigma_b, sigma_c, y_pred_draws(iter, 3), &
                             y_pred_draws(iter, 4))
       end do
    end do
    !$omp end parallel do



end subroutine predictions
```

The only solution I can think of is to create a matrix outside the OpenMP loop that has 3 columns: N, N_samples, and iter. Then I would do my OpenMP loop using that matrix. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Apparently, you could calculate iter = (idx-1) * N_samples + sample  This is a typical change when parallelizing sequential code.

Comment: Just to add to tim18's comment as written the  loop can not be parallelised because of the ordering introduced by incrementing the iter variable. With the suggested change it can be - and as tim18 says this is typical of the thnking you have to do when //ising loops.

Comment: iter must be private.